# Is it possible to match the # part for any route in React Router 5?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

In my app, I'd like to match all routs that end with #something.

```
   /map#login
   /info#login
and
   /map#register
   /map/one#register
   /info#register
   /info/two#register
```

So I can show component as popup on top of the content. How this can be done?

Comment: I don't think it's possible with React Router. This is like using both `BrowserRouter` and `HashRouter` at the same time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a solution for this case. It was inspired from [this question in stackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42033960/is-it-possible-to-match-the-part-of-a-route-in-react-router-4). Using HashRoute wrapper for Route and showing component based on location.hash.

```
const HashRoute = ({ component: Component, hash, ...routeProps }) => (
  <Route
    {...routeProps}
    component={({ location, ...props }) =>
      location.hash === hash && <Component {...props} />
    }
  />
);

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className='App'>
        <Router history={history}>
            <HashRoute hash='#login'component={Login} />
            <HashRoute hash='#register' component={Register} />

            <Switch>
              <Route exact path='/map' component={Map} />
              <Route exact path='/info' component={Info} />
            </Switch>
        </Router>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Updating/improving from the other answer here. It would better to not use the `component` prop as it won't create new instance of the routed component each time the `Route` is rendered for any reason. The custom `HashRoute` component should return valid JSX, either a `Route` component or null.

Example:

```
const HashRoute = ({ hash, ...routeProps }) => {
  const location = useLocation();

  return location.hash === hash
    ? <Route {...routeProps} />
    : null
};
```

...

```
<Router>
  <HashRoute hash='#login' component={Login} />
  <HashRoute
    hash='#register'
    render={props => <Register {...props} otherProp />}
  />
  <HashRoute hash='#something'>
    <Register otherProp />
  </HashRoute>

  <Switch>
    <Route path='/map' component={Map} />
    <Route path='/info' component={Info} />
  </Switch>
</Router>
```

[image: Edit is-it-possible-to-match-the-part-for-any-route-in-react-router-5]